On my Intel Mac, I upgraded brew and cannot use Terminal anymore
Sadly, I exited the Terminal session I used so I cannot show the update information. The symptom I have now is that Terminal starts and instantly exits leaving no trace as to why it exited. I replaced both ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile with "exec 2>> $HOME/tmp/log.txt" but I don't see that file.
Final result: I don't know what I've done so I can't fix it.
Suggestions, anyone?

How did you replace ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile with "exec 2>> $HOME/tmp/log.txt" if Terminal doesn't open any longer?

Missed this: I used a text editor from the finder program. Inserted that line first and put "# " at the start of the rest of the lines. Just brute force.

Good to know. So the update didn’t mangle the startup files but the shell itself.

Does the $HOME/tmp dir exist? I don't think output redirection will create missing intermediate directories.

I assume you're running bash. From the Shell menu in Terminal, select New Command... and enter the following in the dialog that opens:
mkdir disabled_shell_files; mv .profile .bash_history .bash_profile .bashrc disabled_shell_files

Leave the box Run command inside a shell unchecked. You should now be able to open a Terminal window and fix the shell files. Don't do whatever you did before.

Interesting. The command didn't seem to honor the semicolon. It complained that all the ".bash*" files existed. BUT my next attempt was to just move the files and I got an explanatory message: I set my default shell to brew's bash & was forced to use the full path name. bash-5.2.32 was replaced and I can't use a sym link. I'll need to figure out how to exec the thing when the wrong bash runs. Too bad Apple refuses to update. :( 15 year old bash is too old for all my scripts and ways I use the command line tools.

If necessary, run the above list as two separate commands. When you move the shell files, all cusomizations to the shell will of course be lost, and that includes the PATH installed by Homebrew.

That is exactly what I did. Probably should have said so. Thanks.

According to the OP, the Terminal.app immediately exits (crashes?) after he started it.  How would it then be possible to edit the shell menu? But if it is possible, I think it's simpler to configure the shell to do a bash --norc instead of moving files around.


Run, without actually running, the Terminal program
Select "settings" in the menu and click on "general"
Specify "/bin/bash" as the full path, but it didn't work for me
Start by actually running a new shell window
Mine defaulted to the crippled "zsh" so run "chsh -s /bin/bash"

et viola you're good to go again, albeit with a very, very old bash.
Now, to fiddle the system so it uses a current bash without dying the next time homebrew updates it.

On Intel, the homebrew bash is always /usr/local/bin/bash (on Apple Silicon, it's /opt/homebrew/bin/bash). Just keep in mind to restart Terminal (or open a new tab) if you are updating a homebrew-installed bash while running it.

Yep. thanks. However, MacOS will not follow symlinks for a login shell. It has to be an absolute path that has been approved (added to /etc/shells).
So, a curiosity / silly question: why did Apple think it was a good idea to shuffle around standard places just because they switched from i-386 architecture to ARM?

Homebrew changed this, not Apple. Having Homebrew use /usr/local always conflicted with manually installed stuff.

Also, I don‘t have a problem with using /opt/homebrew/bin/bash as my login shell.

If that worked, cool. But for me, /opt/ contains only local/bin/ and local/sbin/, both of which are empty.

That‘s because you have an Intel Mac where brew installs to /usr/local, or didn’t reinstalll Homebrew after migrating to Apple Silicon. Primarily wanted to point out that symlinks work fine in /etc/shells etc.
